# How to map localhost:8080/abcd/efg to just "xyz"

Tags: url, browser, server, alias

I have a web app that I'm developing locally that has a long url like so:

`localhost:8080/abcd/efg` due to reasons I can't help.

Is there a way to map this long URL to a shorter one like "xyz", that would automatically map to the former URL? Something like an alias?

EDIT: Ok I guess I was being vague - I don't mean within my application. I want my computer to map the url `xyz` to `localhost:8080/abcd/efg`, just like a DNS server would do, but on my machine locally.

Comment: Node.js, Apache, whatever? Where do you set your routes? Is it a SPA like Aurelia or Angular?

Comment: If it is angular, this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541695/redirecting-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition

Comment: If using nginx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240376/hide-port-8383-in-glassfish-3-1-2/35240977#35240977